# Unity Hub : Install failed Validation failed

Tags: java, unity-game-engine, sdk, android-ndk

I need a bit of help. I want to install Unity and run my AR app on my Android when I click on the option Build and Run inside Unity. I have installed all of this already on my laptop and everything works ok, but I want to install all the programs and modules etc. on the computer as well. 

[Before clicking on Install, Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrnIj.png)

[After clicking button Install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXeWh.png)

What I did:

1. Installed Unity Hub from the official site: version 3.7.0
2. Tried installing different versions of Unity from the Unity Hub and get the same result as the picture from above
3. Tried manually installing Unity and locating it in Unity Hub, it does locate it and I can open my project, but the Android Support is then missing and I can't Build nor Run my app.
4. Tried manually installing Android support for Unity. It says that it has been installed, but I believe as the links in the Unity app in External Tools Tab suggest that I have inside AndroidPlayer/ folders like OpenJDK, NDK, SDK and stuff like that, I don't. The folder AndroidPlayer is not empty but I do not have those kinda folders that are recommended by default in the app to be used in Unity. Here is what I am talking about: [Android Player folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ASeK.png)
5. I do not have an option Add modules, to add Android support in Unity Hub for the manually installed Unity versions, but I did try by changing one .json file from manual:true, to manual:false, to see the Add modules button, but again unsuccessfull, same error every time.

I do not know what to do, to fix this error and installation but it would mean so much if someone can figure out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you need to look in the log files as to why it failed to install the editor

Comment: @BugFinder how can I check that?

Comment: did google break? mines working it says %UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\UnityHub go look through the log files. look in event log, check your av, if you're gonna be a programmer you're gonna have to learn how to use the tools of your OS